# WebdriverIO: Cannot click drop-down element flash list button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, webdriver-io

I am trying to click on the button **`Edit`** button from drop-down list using WebdriverIO:

[image]

Inspecting the dropdown element yields the following HTML structure:

[image]

Currently using this approach:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()[contains(., '"+"Edit"+"')]]" )).click();
```

Unfortunately it's not woring. How should I proceed to make it work?

Comment: It is recommended to add the html source code instead of image and add the exceptions/errors you encounter while the trials you do.

Comment: Daniel, you are using [WebdriverIO](https://webdriver.io/) framework for this? If so, the answers below, as well as your approach resemble the Java/C# ecosystems. If it is indeed a WDIO question, I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath` 1:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-item' and contains(., 'Edit')]" )).click();
  ```
- `xpath` 2:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-item' and normalize-space()='Edit']" )).click();
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try using *normalize-space* function in Xpath:

`//a[normalize-space(text())='Edit']`